# Access SQL Server Insert blocked by Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

OK we have a multi user (25 users) Access 2013 FE and a SQL Server 2012 BE.  Up until yesterday the whole system was working FINE and now it has completely stopped.

- If user A has a record open via a straight forward select query reading from TABLE Z, then if user B tries to do an insert on TABLE Z, they receive a timeout message.  When I go to SQL server and run SP_WH02, it states User B is blocked by User A.  When I then investigate the command that is blocking user B, it is just a simple SELECT statement.

Does anyone know why this would be?

The form that User A has open has Record Locks = No Locks and Recordset Type = Dynaset

The record source is a SELECT, retrieving two fields where the key field is a parameter based on the value of another.

However, nothing has changed on this system for months, so I'm confused as to why this would happen.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check Access: File->Options->Client Settings->Advanced->Default record locking. Should be "No Locks".

Comment: Is the form of User A a continuous form with many records? If yes, does it work when A goes to the end of the list (so all records are loaded into Access and the record number is displayed)?

Comment: Default record locking = No locks.  Open database by using record-level locking is ticked though?

Comment: It is not continuous no, just a single form.

Comment: UPDATE: We can no longer do any inserts when any user is running a select against Table Z

Comment: Default record locking=No Locks on all PCs?

Comment: Clients use the Access 2013 runtime, and it doesn't allow this setting so I'm assuming it takes it from the 'master' copy

Comment: My question was kinda wrong. Does Table Z have many records (maybe recently increased significantly)? Has the **recordsource** of the form of User A all records, or just one?

Comment: Table Z has 29,502 rows.  Recordsource = all.  However, please see the update - we can no longer perform any insert when a select is performed via Access

Comment: Do you think this is SQL server issue or Access?

Comment: Is your form bound?  You could always switch to an unbound form.

Comment: Hi, it was happening when any select is performed against table Z

Comment: As a note, please use the @Michael syntax when replying to comments, so the user you reply to is notified. -- http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Ok we solved it. If anyone else has the same issue: We archived 9400 records into a new table and now we can do inserts again. It has bought us time so going forward I will normalize table Z further and auto archive records against a criteria.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the same or similar issue as in [MS Access holds locks on table rows indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026199/ms-access-holds-locks-on-table-rows-indefinitely)

Access only fetches the first x rows of the big recordsource, leaving the table in a `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` wait state, i.e. locked.

Possible solutions are:

- Don't have forms or queries that select all records. It usually doesn't make too much sense to scroll through 20k+ records.
- Force Access to fetch all records, to release the lock. You can do this with `Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast` e.g. in `Form_Load()`. Only advisable with a fast network connection.