# Read immediately and process afterwards programing method

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am creating a MS-Access application as a front end for a SQL Server backend. In troubleshooting a lockout problem I have come across several sites that use the phrase "Read immediately and process afterwards" as a way to keep programs like Access from locking tables in SQL Server.

Like this quote from [SQLShack](https://www.sqlshack.com/reducing-sql-server-async_network_io-wait-type/)

> Check whether the application is requesting large data sets from a SQL
> Server instance, and then if it filters those data on the client side.
> Pay attention to third-party applications like Microsoft Access or ORM
> software (aka Object relational mapping) for example, that may be
> requesting the large data sets that they are filtering on the client
> side. Using the read immediately and process afterwards programing
> method may often save users from excessive ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait type
> values

Problem is I've googled that phrase and only come up with suggestions to use it, none on how.  I need to force an Access listbox to read its entire recordset when it opens.  If I open the form with the listbox I get an ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait type that prohibits me from executing code that updates info on the original table.  BUT when I scroll to the bottom of the listbox, the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO disappears.  So I am looking for code to force Access to read the data without analyzing it when the form opens.

Comment: It's not a "software pattern;" it's just a phrase they made up.

Comment: Try putting your Google search "read immediately and process afterwards" in quotes.  Notice that all of the search results link directly back to that single article.

Comment: see this post an a answer to this issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333762/method-for-updating-tables-that-users-are-looking-at/66339006?noredirect=1#comment117464820_66339006